# Pass and use a PHP variable in a Javascript file with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a PHP script in which I get the content of a query made into a Postgresql database :

```
<?php
require_once 'connection.php'; 
$query1 = pg_query("This_is_my_query");
$instruction = "[";
while ($row = pg_fetch_array($query1)) {
    $row1= $row['row1'];
    $row2= $row['row2'];
    $instruction .= "{name : '". $row1. "', y : ". $row2. "},";
}
$instruction .= "]";
echo $instruction;
?>
```

The `echo $instruction` gives :

```
[{name : 'Prestation', y : 1}]
```

Then I have a JS file in which I try to display and use the `$instruction` variable.
I use Ajax and my script is the one :

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'Path_To_Php_File_Is_OK', // requesting a PHP script
    dataType : 'json',
    type: "GET",
    async : false,
    success : function (data) { // data contains the PHP script output
       alert(data);
},
error: function(data) {             
    alert('error');
},
})
```

The result is that the success function is not called and I have the `alert('error')`.
But when I use the dataType 'text' and not 'Json', the success function is ok and I have the `alert(data)`.
**How to explain that behaviour ? And how could I parse the PHP variable `$instruction` ?**

Any help would ve very appreciated, thanks !

Comment: You need to send a JSON header from the PHP I believe. You also should use `json_encode` rather than manual JSON creation.

Comment: Please do not create your own json string. Something will inevitably go wrong. Instead, build up an array or object and use [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. There is no need to create a json string manually. Just build up and array and encode it to json with [json_encode()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php)
2. You **have** to set JSON content-type in the [response headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064444/returning-json-from-a-php-script)
3. Closing `?>` tag is redundant and is not recommended to use (see **[PSR-12](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/)**)

So eventually  your code should look like this

```
<?php

require_once 'connection.php';

$query1 = pg_query("This_is_my_query");

$instructions = [];
while ($row = pg_fetch_array($query1)) {
    $row1 = $row['row1'];
    $row2 = $row['row2'];
    $instructions[] = ['name' => $row1, 'y' => $row2];
}

header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

echo json_encode($instructions);
```

Comment: Great that is working ! Thank you very much @Hast !!